# Elasticsearch: Aggregation with filtering by timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to get a list of **distinct** Ids for a particular day. I am trying to use 'Aggregations' with 'Filtering'. Tried several ways but it's not working. What's the correct format?

```
  {
    "size": "1000",
    "_source": ["Id"],
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": "2020-10-20T00:00:00",
          "lt": "2020-10-21T00:00:00"
        }
      }
    },
     "aggs": {
      "ids": {
        "terms": { "field": "Id.keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
```

Another way I tried:

```
  {
    "size": "1000",
    "_source": ["Id"],
     "aggs": {
      "ids": {
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-10-20T00:00:00",
              "lt": "2020-10-21T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        "terms": { "field": "Id.keyword" }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's @timestamp mapping:

```
"@timestamp": {
   "type": "date",
   "format": "dateOptionalTime"
 }
```

Comment: Could you please add your mapping? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "is not working"? Any error to share?

Comment: The filtering is not working. It returns rows with 'timestamp' value: October 18th 2020, 07:59:32.842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the first option is almost correct. You just need to set size to 0 in the query, remove the `_source` as you won't need it and set size to 1000 in the terms aggregation:

```
{
  "size": "0",
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-10-20T00:00:00",
        "lt": "2020-10-21T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Id.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The filtering is not working. It returns rows with 'timestamp' value: October 18th 2020, 07:59:32.842

Comment: What is the mapping of your index? In the response you're not supposed to have any hits, just aggregations. How are you sending the query?

Comment: Yes the response has only Ids but when I go to Kibana & filter by one of the Ids to ensure it's working all the rows for that Id are from Oct 18th.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'What is the mapping of your index?' How would I find that? Sorry, relatively new to ELK stack.

Comment: What do you get when running `GET your-index-name/_mapping` in Kibana Dev Tools?

Comment: Are you sure your timestamp field is named `@timestamp` and is of type date ?

Comment: Added Timestamp mapping to the original question. Thanks for the tip of _mapping

Comment: Can you also add a sample document that shows up and that you expect not to show up?

Comment: Hmm... I can't share a screen shot of the document. There's PII in it. Let me see what I can do. You will have to take my word for it -:)

Comment: OMG.... I am soooo sorry @Val It's working. I wasn't looking at the correct output. Still waking up. Thanks a LOT for helping me patiently.

Comment: This query always returns rows in descending sequence by number of rows for each Id. I want to say "include only those IDs for which number of documents is less than 2000". Can't figure out how to do that. Any tips?